# Intel NUC - HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, 17.04, intel-nuc

I can connect to my HDMI TV screen via my laptop but cannot via my NUC. Below is the output of `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

What does this `HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)` mean?

Currently I am connecting my NUC to my ASUS screen via USB-C cable.

Any ideas how can I fix this HDMI issue?

My laptop and NUC are both on Ubuntu/ Kubuntu 17.04

**Notes:**

I have tried connecting the HDMI cable to the TV and turning the TV on **before** turning on the NUC. But it makes no difference.

Below is the **Display**s and I **can't** see HDMI being listed:

[image]

EDIT:[image]

Comment: I have a NUC6i3SYH. I connect directly to a monitor's HDMI port, and it works. What model is your NUC ? What monitor are you using with your NUC (if any monitor works)? Maybe you must select/activate the TV's HDMI port (with the remote control of the TV set).

Comment: @sudodus im on NUC Skull Canyon. `What monitor are you using with your NUC (if any monitor works)?` - ASUS MB169C+ is my USB-C monitor.

Comment: @sudodus `Maybe you must select/activate the TV's HDMI port (with the remote control of the TV set).` on my TV screen, I can see HDMI is activated.

Comment: I see. Your NUC is quite different from mine. Is there any setting in the NUC's UEFI-BIOS menues, where you can select/activate the video ports? (In my NUC there is only one video port, and it is a HDMI port, so it is always active.)

Comment: @sudodus HDMI port is already enabled in my UEFI-BIOS - see my edit above. How odd!

Comment: I have no more tip right now, but I will return, if I get some new idea. Let us hope that some people who own the same or a similar model (of NUC) will see your question and share their experience.

Comment: @sudodus thank you for the tips! Yes, let's hope some other people know the answer. Cheers! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60759/discussion-between-sudodus-and-teelou).

Comment: I started with some tips in the chat room ...